# Access Ubuntu partition files using Windows bash

Tags: command-line, partitioning, bash, windows

Is there anyway to access the files of my Ubuntu partition while booted into Windows 10 using the Windows Bash terminal?

I understand there are third party software / drivers that adds support for ext file formats Linux uses and mount them to Windows. After that then you potentially could access it through /mnt/DriveLetter directory.

Hopefully there is a better way than the option I mentioned so there is less chance to corrupt my data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no better way. Windows does not have native support for accessing ext4 or other Linux filesystems. You have to add a third party driver for that.

The risk of data corruption is pretty small, though, compared to accessing NTFS from Linux. While NTFS had to be reverse engineered in order to create a Linux driver for it, Linux filesystem structures are open source and well documented, so the programmers of Windows ext4 drivers had a reliable basis to work from.

Answer (score 0):

As Tilman says, the usual way to do what you want is to use a filesystem driver that makes an Ubuntu (ext2/3/4fs, XFS, Btrfs, etc.) partition work much like a Windows FAT, exFAT, or NTFS partition.

I do know of one other approach: A self-contained program that enables copying and similar operations, but that does not grant access to other programs. An example is [Ext2Read,](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) which works with ext2/3/4 filesystems. I briefly used this program, or something similar, several years ago, but I haven't used it or anything like it more recently. Thus, I can't say how well this specific program works today.

Note that the risks of accessing files via a driver are pretty much the same as the risks of accessing files via a utility like Ext2Read, at least in principle. (There might be bugs in one implementation or another, but there's no reason to think Ext2Read would be any better than a driver, at least not as a general rule.) I haven't been following the Windows drivers (and dedicated programs) for Linux filesystem access very closely, so I can't say what specific programs are likely to be better or worse than others.

Where a driver might be riskier *in general* is in the fact that you're giving every program on Windows access to the Linux filesystem, so if RandomProgram decides it really wants to delete every file called `\etc\fstab` on every disk, then the Ubuntu `/etc/fstab` file will disappear and you'll have problems booting, to name just one of many improbable problem-causing scenarios. Similar comments can be made about user errors, especially if you leave the driver running constantly. Whether you use a driver or a dedicated program, you can minimize such risks by mounting the Linux filesystem read-only -- but if you need to be able to write to the Linux filesystem from Windows, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dual booting, I keep windows in a virtual box virtual machine.  VM has built in method to attach linux directories within windows. Git bash inherits that.

Other good idea is to put a file server between the two machines. I have linux system with Samba offering linux files that appear as windows.  Same idea as using Dropbox to swap files.